# SSRS - DECIMAL to MM:SS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I created a SSRS project where I use a stored procedure with parameters as Dataset.

I have some problems with formatting...

In the procedure I have to cast datetime columns as decimal in order to divide and multiply columns.

This result is in the following format: 0.00035879629629629629
Now how can I format this in SSRS to display MM:SS ?

In Excel I use a custom cell format : [mm]:ss;@

So for example if I format 0.00035879629629629629 in excel with [mm]:ss;@  it returns  00:31.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Did you try the format property of the SSRS cell?

Comment: Yes,I tried a lot of things already but without any success :(

Comment: You say you have to cast datetimes columns as decimals.  Odd, but fine.  That shouldn't make the original datetime columns go away.  Why don't you simply format those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, this will do the trick:

select substring(convert(varchar,cast(0.00035879629629629629 as datetime),14),4,5)

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thank you.Exactly what I wanted :D